# Need advise on OS module in running a command on remote server

Tags: python

I am having difficulty in running below command on remote server. I have tried different modules like. OS & Commands, But none of them able to execute the command as it is. I am getting either syntax error or un-desired output if I add extra quotes. Can somebody please help with this.

```
mminfo -av -ot -q "client=test,savetime>=2 days ago" -r "group,client,sscreate(20),sscomp(20),ssflags,level,name,sumsize,pool" | grep "TEST"
```

Comment: just use `subprocess.run(your_command, shell=True)` `your_command` can be enclosed by single or triple quotes (not double because you are using them in your command).  `'''mminfo -av -ot -q "client=test,savetime>=2 days ago" -r "group,client,sscreate(20),sscomp(20),ssflags,level,name,sumsize,pool" | grep "TEST"'''`

Comment: If you need to run the command on a remote machine, it might be helpfull to look into a module particularly made for this. I suggest to use Paramiko, its very powerfull.

Answer (score 0):

I should have added this as an answer instead of a comment.

Just use [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) `subprocess.run(your_command, shell=True)`

`your_command` can be enclosed by single or triple quotes (not double because you are using them in your command).

`your_command = '''mminfo -av -ot -q "client=test,savetime>=2 days ago" -r "group,client,sscreate(20),sscomp(20),ssflags,level,name,sumsize,pool" | grep "TEST"'''`